# System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Cant seem to fic it

Tags: c#

I keep getting this error. Can somebody help pls?
im trying to create a new file, but it says i dont have acces to the path

this is the part that gets the error

```
        String Newfilepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
        string Newfilepath2 = Newfilepath + @"\Apple";



        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Newfilepath2));
```

Comment: "apple" does not sound like a text file.  You can't overwrite a directory with a file.

Answer (score 2):

Its always best to consult the documentation when you get an exception they usually explicitly tell you what to expect

[FileInfo.CreateText Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.createtext?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Creates a StreamWriter that writes a new text file.

**Exceptions**

- `UnauthorizedAccessException` The file name is a directory.
- `IOException` The disk is read-only.
- `SecurityException` The caller does not have the required permission.

If that doesn't shed any light on the situation. Have a look at your path is that the file name you want?

I assume you want something liek this

```
String Newfilepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
string Newfilepath2 = Newfilepath + @"\Apple.txt";
```

or

```
string Newfilepath2 = Newfilepath + @"\Apple\somefile.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

System.UnauthorizedAccessException means:

your application or idea does not have write permissions for the specific folder, and this is a normal behavior for windows special folders.

Try different folder like **User Documents** or
Run Visual Studio as **Administrator**